# Problem with static files while deploying django with docker-compose

Tags: django, docker-compose, django-staticfiles

I cannot serve the static files on my Django docker compose deployment.
I want it for local deployment, using the built-in web server (runserver)

My docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "./wait-for-mysql.sh mysqldb"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ./app/static:/static
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: proteas2.settings.production
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_PASS: ${DB_PASS}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT:-3306}
      DB_HOST: mysqldb
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - proteas


  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT:-3306}:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
      DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME: ${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME}
      DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL: ${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL}
      DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD: ${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - proteas

networks:
  proteas:
```

I have:

- 'django.contrib.staticfiles'
  in my INSTALLED_APPS
- I tried to set:

```
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

- I ran collectstatic

but did not make it work.

Comment: Did it work before moving into docker?

Comment: Yes, it did....

Comment: Please show your dockerfile and django error log records related to static files when running in docker.